# Possible reasons Curl php script not getting/saving cookies on predefined file - permission and path causes excluded

Tags: php, curl

Ok, I've tried a various scripts that I found and none of them worked.
I'm interested why very basic PHP Curl scripts are not working? Is it about XAMPP?
Here is, for example, my code

```
$ckfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  .'/cookies'  . '/cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/"); // of courese, have cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

which should return cookies in my cookies.txt file. Why is this not happening?
*Notices:*
Ownership is not problem (I have tried with different)
Permissions is not problem (made 777)
Checked file_exists($ckfile), file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. 
No one mentioned that besides ownership, permissions, full path and so, cookie you trying to save to local file must be **server side cookie**, **not the cookies set by javascript**.

Hopes someone will find this helpful.